# How to trigger language in Nuxt js internationalization (i18n) example explanation?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

In Nuxt.Js doc, there is an example of internationalization(i18n). I get most part but What I don't get is how clicking on the Language option on the Navbar menu changing the locale from 'en' to 'fr' or vice versa, which triggers the language swapping.

**Here is the code:** https://nuxtjs.org/examples/i18n

in default layout

```
<nuxt-link class="Header__Link" v-if="$i18n.locale === 'en'" :to="`/fr` + $route.fullPath" active-class="none" exact>
     {{ $t('links.french') }}
</nuxt-link>
<nuxt-link class="Header__Link" v-else :to="$route.fullPath.replace(/^\/[^\/]+/, '')" active-class="none" exact>
     {{ $t('links.english') }}
</nuxt-link>
```

**And here is the live demo:** https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/

Anyone please care to explain?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses [vue-i18n](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n). Have a look `plugins/i18n.js` and `middleware/i18n.js`. So when accessing `/fr/...` for example the locale in the store is set to `fr`.

Comment: Yeah I got it later. Thank you btw.

Comment: I was wondering how one would implement the language switch when there is more than just two languages to toggle between?